# Angular how to send data to backed with `crypted` way?

Tags: angular

In my angular I would like to send datas a `crypted` way. I find there is a module for `angular` called as `bcrypt`.

so instead of sending the data like:

```
var data = {
"name":"user name"
}
```

can i use :

```
bcrypt.hash(data )...
```

like so? if so how the backend will read this again? is this feasible for app development?

or what is the correct approach to send the data to backend?

please help me to understand and show me way.

Comment: Just use SSL/TLS (HTTPS)? Else you'd have to encrypt the data with your servers public key so only the server can decrypt it. Using a fixed key to hash your data on both sides is very unsecure because all JS (angular) files can be reverse engineered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

> crypto-js

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-crypto-js
- https://github.com/brix/crypto-js

to encrypt data from frontend side and decrypt at backend side